# Where does this probability formula come from?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-explanation, solution-verification, bayesian

From Introduction to Probability, 2ed (Bersekas et al), chapter 8.1 p. 417:

[image: pdf]

I would like to ask where the underlined formula comes from.  So far, the formulas given in that chapter are:
[image: 4r]

Please help.  Thank you so much!

Comment: from the 3rd form of Bayes rule ($\Theta$ continuous, $X$ discrete).

Comment: I still don't quite get from to go from there to their answer.

Comment: Oh wait!  The denominator becomes `c`, is that right?